# QnA maker get answer from multiple kb

Tags: azure-qna-maker

Currently i am getting response from single kb in QnA maker.

Current code.

```
  QnAMaker _qnaservice = new QnAMaker(new QnAMakerEndpoint
        {
            EndpointKey = _qnaconfig.AuthKey,
            Host = _qnaconfig.EndPoint,
            KnowledgeBaseId = "{KBID}"
        }, new QnAMakerOptions { Top = 3, StrictFilters = channelData.Filters?.ToArray() });
        var response = await _qnaservice.GetAnswersAsync(stepContext.Context);
```

Is there any option to get results from multiple KBs?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to get the top 3 answers from your KB and you're only getting one, or do you have multiple KBs on QnAMaker and you want to return the top 3 from each? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to get top 3 answers from each KB.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have there pulls the top three answers from just the one kb you have from KBID. You have to code to show three answers, and if you're scorethreshold isn't set, its going to return the answer that's something around 0.3 or higher. Then to display them in chat you're going to have to basically iterate through them. For example:

```
var options = new QnAMakerOptions { Top = 3, ScoreThreshold=0.0F };

var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

var qnaMaker = new QnAMaker(new QnAMakerEndpoint
{
    KnowledgeBaseId = _configuration["QnAKnowledgebaseId"],
    EndpointKey = _configuration["QnAEndpointKey"],
    Host = _configuration["QnAEndpointHostName"]
},
options,
httpClient);


_logger.LogInformation("Calling QnA Maker");

// The actual call to the QnA Maker service.
var response = await qnaMaker.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);
if (response != null && response.Length > 0)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(response[i].Answer), cancellationToken);
    }    
}
```

For my KB, this shows:

[image: Top Three answers displayed in chat]

Now, if you want to show top three answers from multiple KBs, you're going to have to construct multiple QnAMakers

```
var qnaMaker = new QnAMaker(new QnAMakerEndpoint
{
    KnowledgeBaseId = _configuration["QnAKnowledgebaseId"],
    EndpointKey = _configuration["QnAEndpointKey"],
    Host = _configuration["QnAEndpointHostName"]
},
options,
httpClient);

var qnaMaker2 = new QnAMaker(new QnAMakerEndpoint
{
    KnowledgeBaseId = _configuration["QnAKnowledgebaseId2"],
    EndpointKey = _configuration["QnAEndpointKey"],
    Host = _configuration["QnAEndpointHostName"]
},
options,
httpClient);


//LATER IN CODE:
var response = await qnaMaker.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);
var response2 = await qnaMaker2.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);

if ((response != null && response.Length > 0) && (response2 != null && response2.Length > 0))
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Answers from KB1:"), cancellationToken);
    for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(response[i].Answer), cancellationToken);
    }
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Answers from KB2:"), cancellationToken);
    for (int i = 0; i < response2.Length; i++)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(response2[i].Answer), cancellationToken);
    }
}
else if (response != null && response.Length > 0)
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Answers from JUST KB1:"), cancellationToken);
    for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(response[i].Answer), cancellationToken);
    }
}
else if (response2 != null && response2.Length > 0)
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Answers from JUST KB2:"), cancellationToken);
    for (int i = 0; i < response2.Length; i++)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(response2[i].Answer), cancellationToken);
    }
}
else
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("No QnA Maker answers were found."), cancellationToken);
}
```

Then just do the same length check, and SendActivities for each:

[image: all the answers]

Comment: Thanks. Is there any option to merge response and response2?

Comment: Oh yeah. I have them deliniated just because I wanted to show that they came from two separate KBs. It's the bot framework version of a 'print' statement, lol. I literally just iterated through the answers and sent them to the bot. It's ugly, but I'll edit my answer to show what I did.